# Therem of Residue application

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to determinate the following integral:

> $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{e^z}{\cos{(z)}} dz$$
>
> Where $\gamma (t)=\frac{\pi \cos t}{1 +\sin^2 t}(1+i\sin t)$, $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

So I see that $\gamma$ is too much complicated to simplify. I have a feeling that I just need to play with the parametrization and substitute $dz$ by $z'dt$ to make a legitim simplification. But after of some hard work I did get to no where. So I'm asking for tips and another ways to solve this problem :)

Comment: Have you tried to sketch the path?

Comment: Let me try that again... $\gamma(t)=\frac{\pi\cos t}{(1+i\sin t)(1-i\sin t)}(1+i\sin t)=\frac{\pi\cos t}{1-i\sin t}$.

Comment: Do you know the curve is closed or not ? If closed, does the function have poles inside $\gamma$ ?

Comment: Yes... but I need to simplify the path first...

Comment: so try to list roots of $\cos z$

Comment: @ÉlioPereira I think you do not have to, the left factor is a real number, while the right factor is a complex number (which just gets scaled by the real number), so I'd look at the expression as it is.

Comment: @abiessu you did great

Comment: But I still can't get out of there xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contour encircles two singularities of the integrand, at $z=\pm \pi /2$.

The part of the contour that encircles the singularity at $z=+\pi/2$ has counterclockwise orientation, while the part of the contour that encircles the singularity at $z=-\pi/2$ has clockwise orientation.

By the residue theorem, we have

$$\int_C \frac{e^z}{\cos z}=  \left(2\pi i\frac{e^{\pi/2}}{-\sin(\pi/2)}\right) +\left(-2\pi i \frac{e^{- \pi/2}}{-\sin(-\pi/2)} \right)=-4\pi i \cosh(\pi/2)$$

where careful note of the contour's orientation was taken.

Comment: Thank you! Did you mentally visualize the contour? I want to find a way to sketch the path and I don't know how...

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure!  I first plotted the contour by hand and then used a simple Excel spreadsheet to refine the plot.  It's fast and effective.